# Process script for data form - intermittent bug

Tags: php

I have built a data form which runs a little script upon post.  It has an intermittent bug.  The script is supposed to log the entry to the database or die, and then send an email with the details.  I get 100% of the emails but only about 90% of the entries are actually logged to the db.  Can any identify an issue here, an improvement, or a suggestion?  Thanks -

```
$name=$_POST[name];
$email=$_POST[email];
$state=$_POST[state];
$phone=$_POST[phone];
$comments=$_POST[comments];
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

include("config.php");
$link = mysqli_connect("$db_host" , "$db_user" , "$db_password" , "$db") or die();
mysqli_select_db($link, $db) or die();

mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO form (name,email,state,phone,comments,date)
VALUES ('$name','$email','$state','$phone','$comments','$today')");

$Body= " \n";
$Body .= "Contact Request From my_site.com\n\n";
$Body .= "Name: $name\n";
$Body .= "Email: $email\n";
$Body .= "State: $state\n";
$Body .= "Telephone: $phone\n";
$Body .= "Comments: $comments\n";

$Body .= "\n";

mail ("my_email@my_site.com", "Contact Request From my_site.com", $Body, "From: $email");

header("Location: https://www.my_site.com/thank-you/");
die();
```

Comment: You don't check for errors. Call `mysqli_error()` and the mystery will be solved.

Comment: How could I just log the errors to the db for later review?  As mentioned it only fails about 10% of the time.

Comment: You're not escaping the POST parameters. If any of them contain a quote, the SQL will have a syntax error. You should use `bind_param`, or failing that use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: thank you Barmar, can you demonstrate in code how to perform this?

Comment: You should use bind parameters as Barmar suggests and forget about escaping strings; that's left over from before MySql had bind parameters.  Details are here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thank you Barmar and Bob - it was the random ' in the POST -- and have since learned this is a bad vulnerability to not escape the strings (ie SQL injection).  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

POST values not escaped as strings.  Any values containing a single ' quotation was ending the SQL argument and throwing SQL errors and was actually opening a vulnerability (ie SQL injection).

The fix:

```
$name=$_POST[name];
$email=$_POST[email];
$state=$_POST[state];
$phone=$_POST[phone];
$comments=$_POST[comments];
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

include("config.php");
$link = mysqli_connect("$db_host" , "$db_user" , "$db_password" , "$db") or die();
mysqli_select_db($link, $db) or die();

$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email) ;
$state=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $state) ;
$phone=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $phone) ;
$comments=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $comments);
```